# What happens with the electricity in a disconnected wire?

Tags: electricity

I just want my theory confirmed/corrected. Lets say I have a long wire, which gets disconnected from both ends at the same time, where does the electricity go?

My theory is that it goes back and forth until the resistant in the wire "kills" it, which would take a fraction of a second. Alternatively that they electricity itself bleeds out, so even if the wire was 100% free from resistant, the electricity wouldn't last long.

Comment: Electricity corresponds to electrons flowing *uniformly* through the wire at about the pace of a snail. If you disconnect the ends, the electrons simply stop flowing.

Comment: What do you mean "where does the electricity go"? Electricity is not a material object, it doesn't "go" anywhere.

Comment: The charges on the wire don't go anywhere, the wire will stay charged. The magnetic field around the wire, if there was a current flowing, will break down and induce a high EMF voltage on the wire until the element that caused the disconnect starts conducting, again. Inductive sparking is a major source of failure in electrical circuits.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than call it "electricity", I would prefer "current".  But you are correct.

For a disconnected segment, the amount of time the current will continue to flow depends on the capacitance, the resistance, and the starting current.

For for your average "disconnected wire", the capacitance is quite low and resistance is such that there will be very little "ringing" where the current oscillates after it disconnects.

However, you are right that even if the resistance were zero, energy would still depart.  Since the current is oscillating, that means that the charges on the wire are accelerating.  Accelerating charges will lose energy via EM radiation.

Answer (score 0):

The electricity doesn't go anywhere; it's just moving electrons, where the electrons are just part of the material.

As to the "ringing", it isn't due to the momentum of the electrons, but the collapsing of the magnetic field built up by the moving current. The field collapses, causing an electric field (voltage higher at one end than the other). The voltage then collapses in the other direction, causing an opposite magnetic field, and on it goes until it dissipates. I agree with [BowlOfRed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/55662/bowlofred); in your average few feet of wire it would be tough to even measure this. However, if you have a very long wire (even better if it's coiled up to reinforce the magnetic field) then you can get a substantial spark when you break the connection.